# Can a specific line of source code be referred in commit message in git?

Tags: git, commit-message

Can a specific line of source code be referred in commit message in git?

I am trying to mention a specific line having bug in the source code in the commit message and explain how I have debugged that line. This will help in better logging information.

Comment: `file path + file name + ':' + line number`?

Comment: I don't think you need this in the commit message. Anyone who cares about that level of detail can look at the diff generated from the commit by `git log`, `git show`, etc.

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the reply. The need arises when changes in a file consist of both bug correction and feature addition. I felt it would be helpful if it is explicitly mentioned in the commit message in which line bug correction was made. i.e., mainly to differentiate the changes for feature addition made in the file.